# git with tor v3 auth key

Tags: torsocks, authentication, git

I have a git server as a hidden service with v3 auth enabled on it. I of course can browse to the site supplying my private key. I cannot clone from the site over http, because I assume it is expecting the private key. I am using torsocks in conjunction with git, which works when v3 auth is not enabled, but fails when v3 auth is enabled. Is there a configuration that allows torsocks to supply the private key? For instance if I wanted to wget with a private key. Just wondering if anyone has insight, it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try adding the private key to your 'ClientOnionAuthDir' directory specified in your torrc as described here https://community.torproject.org/onion-services/advanced/client-auth/? From what I gather your tor instance should then handle it appropriatley.

Comment: You are correct, this is the only way it will work for him, unless he wants even more bigger security

Comment: Yeah I did do that, but discovered that it only worked if the directory was owned by a certain user and was in /var/lib/tor. So I did get it working, my fault for not reading the error logs sooner. Found it interesting that it requires a particular directory base path